# git diff --numstat different formatting on windows and ubuntu

Tags: git

when I run the following command on windows (git 2.20.1.windows.1):

```
git diff --numstat "F:\diffs\base" "F:\diffs\diff"
```

I get:

```
264     348     "F:\\diffs\\base/a.dasm" => "F:\\diffs\\diff/a.dasm"
```

that I use to get the path to the changed files.

But when I run the same command on ubuntu 18.04 (git 2.20.1):

```
git diff --numstat  /home/diffs/base /home/diffs/diff
```

I get:

```
264     348     /home/diffs/{base => diff}/a.dasm
```

That uses such syntax {base => diff}.

So when I parse it I need to check OS and do it differently for Windows and Ubuntu.

Does anybody know how to get the same output for `git diff --numstat` on both OSes?

Thank you.

Comment: Are the git versions the same in both environments?

Comment: Yes, both use git 2.20.1.